# How to bulk-update a date field in Laravel MongoDB?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, laravel-mongodb

I have a `Device.php` model with `$dates = ['status_updated_at']`.

I'd like to bulk update devices with `Carbon::now()`.

I've tried with the following, which seems straightforward:

```
Device::whereIn('serial_number', $serialNumbers)->update([
    'status_updated_at' => Carbon::now()
]);
```

However, results in an error:

[image]

So I tried saving it as a string instead of the `Carbon::now()` array:

```
Device::whereIn('serial_number', $serialNumbers)->update([
    'status_updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toISOString()
]);
```

However, this does not store it as a date in my DB, it stores it as a string:

[image]

Saving as a date *does* work, and I can achieve this if I save on the model directly, but it results in many unnecessary write operations to the database.

```
$devices = Device::whereIn('serial_number', $serialNumbers)->get();
foreach ($devices as $device) {
    $device->status_updated_at = Carbon::now();
    $device->save();
}
```

I feel like I could be missing something obvious but my current thought is that `laravel-mongodb` package doesn't support this kind of flow...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is documented here:

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/2177

My solution was as follows:

```
$now = (new Device)->fromDateTime(Carbon::now());
Device::whereIn('serial_number', $serialNumbers)->update([
    'status_updated_at' => $now
]);
```

Since `Device.php` is extending the Eloquent `Model` class, that function `fromDateTime()` is accessible and converts correctly before saving.